# Join spark dataset using java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I have 2 datasets which I am trying to combine:

Dataset1(machine):

```
 String machineID:
 List<Integer> machineCat;(100,200,300)
```

Dataset2(car):

```
 String carID:
 List<Integer> carCat;(30,200,100,300)
```

I need to basically get each item of List machineCat from dataset1 and check if that is contained in  List carCat of dataset2. If that matches combine the 2 dataset as below:

final dataset:

```
machineID,machineCat(100),carID,carCat(100)
machineID,machineCat(200),carID,carCat(200)
machineID,machineCat(300),carID,carCat(400)
```

any help on how to do this using dataset join in java.

Looking at an option with arrays_contain(something like below)

```
  machine.foreachPartition((ForeachPartitionFunction<Machine>) iterator -> {

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        Machine machine = iterator.next();
        machine.getmachineCat().stream().filter(cat -> {

            LOG.info("matched");
            spark.sql(
                    "select * from machineDataset m"
                            + " join"
                            + " carDataset c "
                            + "where array_contains(m.machineCat,cat)");
            return true;
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: is this too complex????

Comment: You can `explode` list values, it will produce machineId and machineCat (String,Integer) columns, do the same for dataset2 and then join by macineCat = carCat and thats all,finally  if you want 1-element array use `array("machineCat")` function

Comment: @chlebek Dataset1(machine) and Dataset2(car) contain much more elements than a list and string(more than 30 ) . Do you still think exploding list would be easy. Can you elaborate?

Comment: this should not bother until you explode more than one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*; // before main class

Machine machine = new Machine("m1",Arrays.asList(100,200,300));
Car car = new Car("c1", Arrays.asList(30,200,100,300));

Dataset<Row> mDF= spark.createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(machine), Machine.class);
mDF.show();
Dataset<Row> cDF= spark.createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(car), Car.class);
cDF.show();
```

output:

```
+---------------+---------+
|     machineCat|machineId|
+---------------+---------+
|[100, 200, 300]|       m1|
+---------------+---------+

+-------------------+-----+
|             carCat|catId|
+-------------------+-----+
|[30, 200, 100, 300]|   c1|
+-------------------+-----+
```

then

```
Dataset<Row> mDF2 = mDF.select(col("machineId"),explode(col("machineCat")).as("machineCat"));
Dataset<Row> cDF2 = cDF.select(col("catId"),explode(col("carCat")).as("carCat"));
Dataset<Row> joinedDF = mDF2.join(cDF2).where(mDF2.col("machineCat").equalTo(cDF2.col("carCat")));
Dataset<Row> finalDF = joinedDF.select(col("machineId"),array(col("machineCat")), col("catId"),array(col("carCat")) );
finalDF.show();
```

and finally:

```
+---------+-----------------+-----+-------------+
|machineId|array(machineCat)|catId|array(carCat)|
+---------+-----------------+-----+-------------+
|       m1|            [100]|   c1|        [100]|
|       m1|            [200]|   c1|        [200]|
|       m1|            [300]|   c1|        [300]|
+---------+-----------------+-----+-------------+

root
 |-- machineId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- array(machineCat): array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- catId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- array(carCat): array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: My result shows:

[1172573,WrappedArray(141),549,WrappedArray(141)]
[1172573,WrappedArray(1653),3155,WrappedArray(1653)]
[1172573,WrappedArray(191),1412,WrappedArray(191)]

how do i expand this WrappedArray?